# Any other optimize way to write this code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
for col in df.columns:
if not df[col].astype(str).str.contains('-->').any() and not col in ['ETL_ID','CLAIM_ID']:
    df.drop(col, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

I just want to keep the columns (of all rows) in dataframe, where ever even single substing '-->' exists. If substring doesn't exist (in any row) I need to drop those columns except few columns like ETL_ID...
Any other optimize way to write above code
Or
I just want those records in my dataframe which contains substring '-->'

Answer (score 0):

How about using `any`?

```py
mask = df.eq('-->').any()
df = df[mask[mask == False].index.tolist() + ['ETL_ID','CLAIM_ID']]
```

I don't like `mask[mask == False].index.tolist()` but cannot figure out to do the `any()` within the filtering.